# How to see which SQL Server objects are referenced in a C# Github Repo?

Tags: sql-server, github

We have a large SQL Server database with thousands of objects and a backend C# project in Github that references a couple hundred of those objects.

What is the best way to see which of those SQL Server objects are referenced by a specific C# project? I know we can manually search through the repo or we can search for each object one by one but is there an easier way to do this in bulk?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried loading the project into Visual Studio and using appropriate IDE features to search for definitions and references? It's hard to give more specific advice without knowing how your backend code refers to your RDBMS tables, views, stored code, and so forth.

Comment: Mostly straight SQL inside the code - all types of objects (tables, views, stored procedures)

Comment: There is no good way.  If you're writing SQL within C# then your best bet is to manually catalog the objects.